# How do I change the default author and committer in the Eclipse Git plugin?

Tags: git, eclipse, default, egit, author

I am using the `Git plugin` for `Eclipse`. I have several authors and committers which are displayed when I start typing in those fields.

How can I provide changes to this list, or remove some author or committer?

Also, I want to set my default author and committer which will be displayed by default.

[image]

Answer (score 192, accepted):

1. Click **Window > Preferences > Team > Git > Configuration**
2. Click **Add Entry** and enter the key value pairs:

   - Key:  **user.name**
   - Value: *YourUsernameHere*

     And
   - Key:  **user.email**
   - Value: *YourEmailHere*

Comment: I had to [set a HOME environment variable](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/598634/) before I could add a new entry. Then this worked for me.

Comment: Restart eclipse after adding configuration.

Comment: Note that this solution only applies to a single git repository at a time. If you use multiple repositories, you should use the global solution in the answers provided by GorvGoyl or GoZoner.

Answer (score 25):

Each developer should perform:

```
git config --global user.name "<name of user>"
git config --global user.email "<email of user>"
```

If you want to change the author of an existing commit, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/1286639)

Comment: agree, then Eclipse will use config from `YOUR_HOME_DIR/.gitconfig`, which is set by those 2 commands above

Comment: works and more global than to do it only in eclipse!

Answer (score 18):

### Changing Your Committer Name & Email Globally

You can run the "`git config`" command with the `--global` flag; this will make sure all of your future commits use the given information:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email "john@doe.org"
```

### Changing Your Committer Name & Email per Repository

If you want to use special settings only when working in a certain repository, you can simply omit the `--global` flag. This makes the configuration valid only in that repository:

```
$ git config user.name "John Doe"
$ git config user.email "john@doe.org"
```

---

Git Cheatsheet: [git for dummies](https://github.com/JerryGoyal/Git-for-Dummies)

Comment: This is a much better answer for those using multiple workspaces and need different Authors/Committers for each workspace instead of a global Eclipse setting.

Comment: Agree with @Etep. I've configured both global and local accounts. To check if you're using correct repo specific account from within repo, run `cat .git/config` or `git config --local user.name`

Answer (score 14):

EGit should ask you the first time you commit something. But you can always change it later on, see here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Identifying_yourself

Answer (score 9):

In [Eclipse v4.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Luna) it will work like the below way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The team section is now called version control(team)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).