# How to change git username in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

It's quite weird to me that eclipse always show up default `git` username when make Commit and Push. Shown below：

[image]

Have been changed the git username and email as followed the instruction introduced [How do I change the default author and committer in the Eclipse Git plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663492/how-do-i-change-the-default-author-and-committer-in-the-eclipse-git-plugin#)

But problem still remains, any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: That screenshot is showing a login dialog asking for the username and password required to authenticate when **pushing**. It is likely not the same as the committer/author name. What happens if you check the "Store in Secure Store" after changing the username and password in the dialog shown?

Comment: The `git` username shown in the dialog cannot be changed, I cannot figure out the reason@LasseV.Karlsen

Answer (score -1):

You don't change that user. Github uses user `git` and your ssh key to figure out who you are when you push. You should leave that configuration as it is, because it is correct and should not be altered.